# Whats the difference between a clearnet site and an onion site?

Tags: onion-routing

Why are clearnet sites on the hidden wiki etc if they are not really secure or hidden? Whats the difference between an onion site and a clearnet site?

Thanks.

Comment: Well it is a wiki. Content depends on the person who edits the contents.

Answer (score 1):

The clearnet sites that appear on such wikis are (presumably) sites that are restricted in certain areas of the world. For example, the search engines in China don't index websites that the Chinese government don't want people to visit. In addition, any connections to those websites are blocked.

If the websites aren't indexed by the search engines, then people can't search for them and find them (i.e. they are *hidden* from those people, even though they're on the clearnet). These wikis provide a way of finding those sites, regardless of whether they're hidden services or clearnet websites. Tor then also allows a way to circumvent any blocks on connection.

Answer (score 0):

No differences at all - they're just using a "clearnet"="direct IP routing" or "darknet"="onion packet routing" respectively. And - dot-onion sites can use TCP only, because Tor does not support UDP

Comment: Except the difference that onion sites are not available on the clear net.